# How do I disable Coldfusion for one site?

Tags: iis, coldfusion

I have multiple sites on my coldfusion webserver.  I want to make a new site that does not allow coldfusion to run.  At the same time I do not want to disable coldfusion on the other sites.

I am running coldfusion standard edition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In IIS, find the Application Configuration Window where all the extensions are listed and which Executable they are linked to.

Just delete the one for .cfm and any other extension that links to the ColdFusion dll
[alt text http://www.fastpics.net/sharepics/imih41904722.jpg](http://www.fastpics.net/sharepics/imih41904722.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Like Zarko said - What webserver are you referring to? If it's ColdFusion's own application server (JRun) then you've got a difficult task here.

If you're running things through a webserver, like IIS or Apache, before hitting CF then the simplest thing to do is not create files with the .cfm, .cfc etc. extensions on them.

Use HTML instead OR remove the JRun Connections from the website / host that is going to be running this other site.

--

Same applies for it you want to run other languages like PHP off the same server. Tell the webserver which drivers to use for which site and it'll pass the request onto the correct application server to be processed.

Comment: in addition to what James suggested, I would also setup a filter for the site in question, and have it watch for requests to ".cfm" and ".cfc" and redirect the browser to a different page.  You'll want to have that filter before the coldfusion filter.

Answer (score 1):

The other thing to watch out for is the CFIDE virtual directory.  This won't be a problem if you create a new site from scratch, but if your disabling CF on an existing site you should remove the virtual directory.

Answer (score 0):

Which webserver? If you run standard standalone installation I'm afraid you can't do that without digging into deep dark places of configuration files. If it's IIS or Apache or whatever, than it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler, just do not use any cfml code or create any new datasources for the other sites.

Just don't use any coldfusion code for your other site.

Or you can disable the http handler's for coldfusion for this other site.

But if this other site does not include any .cfc or .cfm files than that is not a coldfusion site. That's all there to it.

Why does it matter?

Comment: I can think of several instances where I might want to disable CF on one site.  For example, in a small hosting company, you might disable CF on specific sites to prevent users from using it on static site packages.